# ${abbr} заменить текствым значением

Tags: javascript, dom, tag

Подскажите,пожалуйста,как сделать чтоб вместо ${abbr} появился текст "css"?

```
function addCenter() {
    var article = document.createElement("article");
    article.setAttribute("role", "main");
    var header = document.createElement("header");
    var h2 = document.createElement("h2");
    var abbr = document.createElement("abbr");
    h2.appendChild(abbr);
    h2.innerHTML = `The Beauty in ${abbr} Design.`;
    abbr.innerHTML = "css";
```

Answer (score 1):

В переменной `abbr` в Вашем случае хранится элемент, а не текст. Чтобы получить текстовое содержимое `abbr` следует обратиться к текстовому узлу: `abbr.textContent`. Стоит учесть, что `abbr.textContent` должен иметь значение до его присвоения в `h2.innerHTML`. 
Рабочий пример:

```js
var h2 = document.createElement('h2');
var abbr = document.createElement('h1');
abbr.innerHTML = 'wow! it works!';

h2.innerHTML = `My cool text: ${abbr.textContent}`;

document.body.appendChild(h2);
document.body.appendChild(abbr); // only for example
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!

Comment: Даже не знал про такое, спасибо)